# How to return a response if the regex validation fails in laravel?

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I am developing one API which is responsible for registering the users and the data should store in database upto this part it's working fine, i want to add regex patterns for validation part ,for example if the user mobile number not matches with the regex pattern then it should return a response like `Please enter valid mobile number` like this i want  How to acheive this thing please help me ..

`UserController.php`

```
public function Registration(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10',
            ]);
        $admin = new AdminModel([
            'firstName' => $request->input('firstName'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile' => $request->input('mobile'),
        ]);
        $admin->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Admin registered successfully']);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add validation messages

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'firstName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10',
            ],[
        'mobile.required' => 'Please enter mobile number',
        'mobile.digits' => 'Please enter valid mobile number',
    ]);
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Check updated code, you can add custom messages for any validation rules.

Comment: it's printing some other message, means it's printing my project message

Comment: Can you share the message?

Comment: Welcome to Apiato this message is coming